# How do I add Slack to the menu bar in Mac?

Tags: macos, slack

Slack shows the latest number of messages in the Dock but I like to hide the Dock by default, so I don't see them. Is there a way to put the Slack icon (with the number of messages) into the menu bar instead?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After searching around I've found an open-source app [called Doll](https://github.com/xiaogdgenuine/Doll) that can put *any* Dock app into the menu bar, including Slack. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm not the author of Doll and don't know who wrote it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing Doll, the pleasure is mine :) . I just release v0.0.6 with couple fixes and improvements, check them out~ https://github.com/xiaogdgenuine/Doll/releases/tag/v0.0.6